# Am I correct in thinking that $A = B \cup C = B \cup D \not\implies C = D$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

One of my textbooks has a problem of this form:

> If $A = B \cup C = B \cup D$, can we conclude that $C = D$?

Am I correct in thinking that it's almost trivial because I can't just "cancel" the $B$ show that $C \neq D$? I'm thinking along the lines of $A = B \cup C = B \cup D \not\implies C = D$ because (for example), $C = \varnothing$ and $D \subseteq B, D \neq \varnothing$ still satisfies the equation, but $C \neq D$.

Comment: I think you forget something in the statement of your problem, what's D?

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti Sorry, I confused the problem with another one below it (the textbook isn't about set theory, but I'm asking about the general form). I corrected my question.

Comment: Careful with that $\not \implies$ symbol.  $\lnot \forall x P(x) \implies Q(x)$ isn't the same thing as $\forall x P(x) \not \implies Q(x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want that 
$$B\cup C= B\cup D \implies C=D.$$

Rewrite it as
$$(B\setminus C)+(B\cap C)+(C\setminus B)=(B\setminus D)+(B\cap D)+(D\setminus B),$$
where $+$ stands for disjoint union.

It is equivalent to have $C\setminus B= D\setminus B$.

How this could implies $C=D$? Well, if $B$ is non-empty, it cannot be true.

Comment: Your proof that you can cancel in a union cancels in a (disjoint) union, so it seems a little circular.

Answer (score 2):

The statement is true iff $B=\emptyset$. Obviously if $B=\emptyset$ then $C=B\cup C=B\cup D=D$. If $B\ne\emptyset$, then setting $C=\emptyset,D=B$ gives $B\cup C=B\cup\emptyset=B$ and $B\cup D=B\cup B=B$, but $C\ne D$.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that you can't just cancel from each side.

Try a small example for a counter example.

Let $B=\{1,2,3\}$, $C=\{1,2\}$, and $D=\{2,3\}$.

Then $B \cup C = B \cup D$ but $C \ne D$